# Bootstrap 4 Trouble aligning 3 images with links attached on a single row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So im working on my portfolio for a class project and Im struggling with aligning my projects on a single row. Here is what I have / need help with....

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Designird/pen/JwLQoj" target="_blank" class="project project-title">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/8TGwqfY.jpg" alt="project">
                <div class="project-tile">Howard Stern Tribute Page</div>
            </a>
      </div>
     </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="https://codepen.io/Designird/pen/Jwemdd" target="_blank" class="project project-title">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/UtN8xFJ.jpg" alt="project">
                <div class="project-tile">Product Landing Page</div>
            </a>
      </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="https://codepen.io/Designird/pen/xmoWLB" target="_blank" class="project project-title">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/lY9IvVn.jpg" alt="project">
                <div class="project-tile">UFO Sighting Survey</div>
            </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed was that you have too many closing `</div>` tags. You should indent your code properly so it would be easy to notice that. I added `img-fluid` class to images so they are responsive and do not overflow the container.

Check out the snippet below in full screen.

I removed many elements and I left what was important to solve the problem. i hope it helps.

You should also check out Bootstrap documentation, you have everything there. [LINK](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/8TGwqfY.jpg" alt="">
        <div>Howard Stern Tribute Page</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/UtN8xFJ.jpg" alt="">
        <div>Product Landing Page</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/lY9IvVn.jpg" alt="">
        <div>UFO Sighting Survey</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jakub, my brother, thank you so much! you dont know the stress you just got off my back. I was going nuts over this.